# Possible to combine top panel bar and dock?

Tags: wingpanel, plank

Is is possible to combine top panel bar and dock? My best option would be that combined bar to show on the top, always visible.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on exactly what you mean by combining them? Do you just want them to both be in the same region of the screen?

Comment: Im looking for the same thing, this is pretty much my idea: [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VMn0u.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VMn0u.jpg) But when i'm going to click one of the icons the top panel get in my way and put himself over the icons

Comment: As the plank panel is easy to move (right click on it to access preferences) this question amounts to the problem of **editing the panel so that it leaves place for the dock**.

Answer (score 1):

As far I know, no. You can change the position of this dock using `elementary-tweaks`, but if you move it on the top, it will go under the top panel which is not really convenient, because you barely can click items.

Comment: Thanks for elementary-tweaks: this is the first step into the solution!

Comment: Thanks for elementary-tweaks: this is the first step of the solution!

Continuing on that: I discovered that is possible to move the dock to the left, so there it isn't in the way anymore.

But the top bar panel is not so configurable: how could I customize it the way I could customize the xfce-panel bar, or the lxde=panel bar?

Comment: It probably is not possible due to its nature.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that Plank comes with the option to be shown at the top acts as a bug in the context of the elementary desktop, as it interferes with the panel (Wingpanel) no matter what. The question amounts to how to reduce the panel **length** (left-right size) in order to leave some space for the dock at the top. They cannot be combined.

I don't think that reducing the panel length is possible, but I have posted a specific [question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/14086/can-panel-size-be-edited) on that in order to have a clear answer.

---

On the other hand, for what it's worth, as this is a matter of gaining display space: the elementary desktop has its own way of taking advantage of display space through the use of shortcuts that may remove the need for what we ask here. Super-A and Super-S, along with Alt-Tab and Super-Tab allow access to windows and workspaces.

Adding a shortcut like Super-F to "Toggle Fullscreen" may also be a good idea. The fullscreen mode assigns to each window its own workspace, which can be cycled with Super-Tab.

[image]

That might also reduce the need for the dock to be always visible, hence more display space.